# How to convert std::chrono::timezone convert HowardHinnant date library

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I have this code in C++20 running fine under MSVC. However, my GCC version does not support timezone, so I wanted to use Howard Hinnant library.

```
#include <chrono>

using LocalTime = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::local_t, std::chrono::system_clock::duration>;
//using LocalTime = std::chrono::local_time<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>;

using UtcTime = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;

LocalTime UtcToLocal(UtcTime t)
{       
    auto tz = std::chrono::current_zone();
    LocalTime tLocal = tz->to_local(t);
    return tLocal;
}

UtcTime LocalToUtc(LocalTime t)
{
    auto tz = chronoExt::current_zone();
    UtcTime tUtc = tz->to_sys(t);

    return tUtc;
}
```

If I change code to:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include "date.h"

LocalTime UtcToLocal(UtcTime t)
{       
    auto tz = date::current_zone();
    LocalTime tLocal = tz->to_local(t);
    return tLocal;
}

UtcTime LocalToUtc(LocalTime t)
{
    auto tz = date::current_zone();
    UtcTime tUtc = tz->to_sys(t);

    return tUtc;
}
```

In MSVC I got errors:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t,std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::system_clock::rep,std::chrono::system_clock::period>>' to 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::local_t,std::chrono::system_clock::duration>'
message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
error C2672: 'date::time_zone::to_sys': no matching overloaded function found
message : could be 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,common_type<_Duration,std::chrono::seconds>::type> date::time_zone::to_sys(std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t,Duration>,date::choose) const'
message : 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,common_type<_Duration,std::chrono::seconds>::type> date::time_zone::to_sys(std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t,Duration>,date::choose) const': expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
message : or       'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,common_type<_Duration,std::chrono::seconds>::type> date::time_zone::to_sys(std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t,Duration>) const'
message : 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,common_type<_Duration,std::chrono::seconds>::type> date::time_zone::to_sys(std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t,Duration>) const': could not deduce template argument for 'std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t,Duration>' from 'LocalTime'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get Howard Hinnant's date library working on C++ 20 on both msvc and gcc. There are some advantages, e.g. if you want to be sure you have the same timezone database on both Windows and linux (or if your Windows box isn't recent enough to support the timezone database), and obviously if you're unable to upgrade to the latest gcc for corporate reasons. However if you possibly can, I'd recommend upgrading to gcc13 -- I've done this and everything *just works* on Windows and linux :).

To get the dates library to work, you need to be very careful about what you pick from which library (i.e. which bits come from `date` and which from `std::chrono`). I'd recommend importing what you need from `std::chrono` into the `dates` namespace, and then using the `dates` namespace throughout your code. In your case, specifically, `local_t` needs to come from `date` not `std::chrono`. I.e.

```
using LocalTime = std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t, std::chrono::system_clock::duration>;
```

To get your program to compile with/without dates.h, I set up some conditional compilation

```
#define HHDATE
#ifdef HHDATE
#include "date/tz.h"
#include "date/date.h"
#else
#include <chrono>
namespace date = std::chrono;
#endif
```

(Note also that if you use the very useful ostream insertion feature's of HH's library, then the line `return (os << sys_time<Duration>{ut.time_since_epoch()});` can be reported as ambiguous in Visual C++ in which case can be changed to `return date::operator<<(os, sys_time<Duration>{ut.time_since_epoch()});`.)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend something like this:

```
#if USE_DATE_LIB

#include "date/tz.h"

namespace chronoExt = date;

#else  // !USE_DATE_LIB

namespace chronoExt = std::chrono;

#endif
```

I.e. `#define USE_DATE_LIB 1` (or `0`) to tell the compiler which namespace to look in for the C++20 chrono bits.  On MSVC use `USE_DATE_LIB = 0` and on gcc (prior to 14) use `USE_DATE_LIB = 1`.

Then you can say:

```
using LocalTime = std::chrono::time_point<chronoExt::local_t, std::chrono::system_clock::duration>;

using UtcTime = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;

LocalTime UtcToLocal(UtcTime t)
{       
    auto tz = chronoExt::current_zone();
    LocalTime tLocal = tz->to_local(t);
    return tLocal;
}

UtcTime LocalToUtc(LocalTime t)
{
    auto tz = chronoExt::current_zone();
    UtcTime tUtc = tz->to_sys(t);

    return tUtc;
}
```

And things should just work.